# Get static class name from extended class JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, static

I can get a caller's class through `this.constructor.name` in an object when it is instantiated.

As an example:

```js
class Foo {

    /**
     * Get called class
     * @returns {String}
     */
    getCaller() {
        return this.constructor.name;
    }

};

class Bar extends Foo {


};

var foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.getCaller()); // Foo

var bar = new Bar();
console.log(bar.getCaller()); // Bar
```

Now I need to call basically the same function, but from a static function within the extender.

```js
class Foo {

    /**
     * @static
     * Get called class
     * @returns {String}
     */
    static getCaller() {
        return this.constructor.name; // <- any ideas?
    }

}

class Bar extends Foo {


}

console.log(Foo.getCaller()); // function
console.log(Bar.getCaller()); // function
```

Comment: You know javascript classes are a big mess, right?

Comment: Yes, they are also quite good to be honest.

Comment: BTW, static methods do not belong to the instances so `this` doesn't make sense inside them

Comment: I know, the question is how to retrieve the static caller.

Comment: Why do you need this when you have to write the class name when you want to call the static function?

Comment: So I can dynamically load configurations by extending a config class which loads a config based on class name. `static config(property) { return Configurable.get(this.name)[property] || null; }`

Answer (score 1):

```js
class Foo {

    /**
     * @static
     * Get called class
     * @returns {String}
     */
    static getCaller() {
        return this.name;
    }

}

class Bar extends Foo {


}

console.log(Foo.getCaller()); // Foo
console.log(Bar.getCaller()); // Bar
```

Comment: Thanks that's much neater!